# Symmetric multivariable integral proof

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $G \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $\;(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in G \iff (-x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in G$.

Let $f$ be an integrable function in $G$ such that $$f(-x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)=-f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$$
I'm trying to prove that for each $(x_1, x_2, …, x_n) \in G$ we get $$\underset{G}{\int\hspace{-0.5ex}\cdots\hspace{-0.75ex}\int}\;f\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right) dx_1\dots dx_n = 0$$

I've tried to integrate by substitution, but couldn't arrive at a solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the diffeomorphism $\Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) := (-x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and the integral transformation theorem for the integral on $G_- := \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in G : x_1 < 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion solved the problem easily.